# Is it possible to force datatype of tensorflow op?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using mixed precision computations in Tensorflow and I would like to force certain ops to be computed on float32. I'd like to do something like:

```
relu = tf.nn.relu(input, dtype='float32')
```

This doesn't work because there's no keyword argument 'dtype' for this operation. It's just to illustrate my point. Can I force specific ops to be computed with specifid datatype in some other way?

Comment: Can you use `tf.keras` instead of `tf.nn`? If so, than `tf.keras.layers.Activation` has the desired `dtype` attribute, allowing you to switch between fp16 and fp32.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your input before feeding it into `tf.nn.relu` by using [`tf.cast`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast):

`relu = tf.nn.relu(tf.cast(input, dtype=tf.float32))`